# A question on the basic properties of the little group of the 1st kind.

Tags: group-theory

Can someone please help me with the basic properties of the little group of the 1st kind?

Let $K$ be an invariant subgroup of a group $G$:
$$K \lhd G\;.$$

If $\Delta (K)$ is an irreducible representation of $K$, then 
 $$\Delta_g(K) \equiv \Delta (g^{-1} K g)$$
is an irreducible representation also.

All representations
$$ \{\;\Delta_g(K)\;|\;g\in G  \;\} $$
make an orbit. The orbit can be parameterised by any representation belonging to it.

The entire set of irreducible representations of $K$ can be presented as a set of non-intersecting orbits.

${\underline{\mbox{Definition.}}}~~$

For an arbitrary irreducible representation $\Delta$, the little group of the 1st kind is defined as
$$  H = \left\{\;h\in G\;|\;\Delta(K) \sim \Delta_h (K)  \right\}\;. $$

${\underline{\mbox{Lemma 1.}}}~~$

Representations belonging to the same orbit have their little groups interrelated as $H' = g H g^{-1}$ and therefore isomorphic to one another.

${\underline{\mbox{Proof:}}}~~$

If we define $H'$ as
$$ H' = \left\{\;h'\in G\;|\;\Delta_g(K) \sim \left(\Delta_g\right)_{h'}(K) \;\right\}\;,$$
this definition implies, for an arbitrary $k_1\in K$:
$$
\Delta(g^{-1} k_1 g) \sim \Delta (g^{-1} h'^{-1} k_1 h' g) = \Delta \left(\;(g^{-1} h'^{-1} g) \; (g^{-1}k_1g)\;(g^{-1} h' g)\;\right)\;.
$$
 Recalling that $K \lhd G$, we see that $k = g^{-1} k_1 g \in K$, so we may write the above equation as
$$
\Delta(k) \sim \Delta \left(\;(g^{-1} h'^{-1} g)\;k\;(g^{-1 }h g)\;\right)\;.
$$
Comparing this with the definition of $H$, we see that $(g^{-1} h' g)\in H$, whence $H' = g H g^{-1}$.

QED

${\underline{\mbox{Lemma 2.}}} \qquad K< H$

${\underline{\mbox{Proof.}}} ~~$

For an arbitrary fixed $k\in K$ and for all $k'\in K$, we have: 
$$
\Delta_{k'}(k) = \Delta( k'^{-1}\,k\,k') = \Delta^{-1}(k') \Delta(k) \Delta(k')\quad \Longrightarrow\quad \Delta_{k'}(k) \sim \Delta(k)
$$
QED

Now a question: is the subgroup $K$ invariant $\,\underline{\mbox{in}\;H}\,$?

Can we claim that $K\lhd H\,$?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

More generally if $K\le H\le G$ and $K\trianglelefteq G$ then $K\trianglelefteq H$.

$K\trianglelefteq G$ if and only if $g^{-1}Kg=K$ for all $g\in G$, so certainly $h^{-1}Kh=K$ for all $h\in H$, hence $K\trianglelefteq H$.